# On clicking second username or password input box, cursor jumps to first

Tags: html, css, forms

The 3 forms allow access as member, guest or then as newly registered.
However if someone clicks on the lower part of the form it automatically sends the cursor to the top part.

```
<form action="schlogin.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Member's Login</legend>
    <label for="username">Username: 
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
    </label>
    </br>
    <label for="password">Password: 
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
    </label>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" class="loginButtons" value="login"/>
    </label>
    </br>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form action="schlogin.php" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Guest Player</legend>
    <input type="submit" name="guest" class="loginButtons" value="Play as GUEST!" />
    </label>
    </br>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form action="schlogin.php" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>FAST Register</legend>
    <label for="username">Username: 
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value =""/>
    </label>
    </br>
    <label for="password">Password: 
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
    </label>
    </br>
    <label for="email">E-mail:
        <input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
    </label>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="register" class="loginButtons" value="I WANT TO PLAY TOO!"/>
    </label>
    </br> 

    I've forgotten my password:
    <input type="submit" name="forgotten" class="loginButtons" value="Send me a new password!"/>
    </label>
    </br>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Please don't post your PHP code. This is an HTML issue so show your HTML only.

Comment: A side note: You forgot a bracket `if (isset($username)) {echo $username; }`  in the first bit of your code.

Comment: @Rick Kuipers Very observant thanks! (however the original code was ok - it was lost in formatting for SO!)

Comment: As a side note, your HTML contains several incorrect `</br>` tags, which clearly should have been `<br/>` and there are also a few closing `</label>` tags without an opening counterpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second form change

```
<label for="username">Username: 
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value ="<?php if (isset($username)){echo $username; }?>"/></label></br>
```

to:

```
<label for="register_username">Username: 
<input type="text" name="username" id="register_username" value ="<?php if (isset($username)){echo $username; }?>"/></label></br>
```

or whatever you like.

The point is that the id for every html element should always be unique. And the label element's for attribute should match it's associated input element's id attribute.

Comment: thanks for the more complete answer, including the need to rename labels as well as id. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

[Validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org).

You have duplicate id attributes, so the labels in your second form are `for` the inputs in the first form.

Comment: Thanks for the speed, I marked it up but I gave the tick to the more complete answer. Thanks tho!